# Can't login: user/login redirects to index page

Tags: users

My Drupal 7 user, user login and admin pages all redirect to the index page. I am unable to login at all. This problem came up recently after the site had been unchanged for months.   I can't think of a single reason this started happening all of a sudden.

- http://sohp.us/?q=user
- ... ?q=user/login
- ... ?q=admin

Nothing looks funny when I debug in my browser. I have the following details based on my research:

- No errors are appearing.
- There were no updates, automatic or manual, to the site or modules.
- I'm not using Secure Pages, Ubercart SSL, or any other SSL modules that might interfere. The site is pretty basic, simple Zurb Foundation theme, Views, and a couple other small modules, nothing fancy.
- `$base_url = 'http://sohp.us'; // NO trailing slash!`  Is specified in my `settings.php` file (located in root/public_html)
- The Drupal instance was installed through cPanel's Softaculous
- I downloaded the default `.htaccess` for Drupal 7 and replaced the existing one (no changes required).

It seems like the PHP for bringing up the login isn't working correctly, but I could definitely be missing something obvious or compeltely different from what I've been trying. If anyone has any suggestions on things to test out to get myself back in, it is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: How exactly your headers looks like?

Comment: When was the last time you updated the site? What version of Drupal?

Comment: A few years late for this comment, but one thing that can happen to cause this is if mod_rewrite somehow gets disabled on Apache. If anyone comes across this in the future, you can check that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have drush installed? I would try clearing cache as a first step, probably won't fix it but worth a shot. After that try renaming the theme that you are using to force Drupal to use a different theme, or change the theme manually in the database. Try disabling modules one by one to see if any of them might be interfering. Start with any module that changes paths (like PathAuto...). I also noticed that no matter what your site will not throw a 404 page not found error. If that was intended, then whichever process you used to redirect 404's to index.php could possibly be causing an issue.